# Sum of columns in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
`SELECT order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method,

    sum(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then 1 else 0 end) paid,
    sum(case `order`.order_status when 'later' then 1 else 0 end) later
FROM order_customFields 
  INNER JOIN `order` ON order_customFields.order_id = `order`.order_id

where `order`.order_createdAt >= date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day), interval 1 month) 
and `order`.order_createdAt < date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day)
AND order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method in('a','b','c','d','e')
GROUP BY    
   order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method`
```

How can I get total sum for colums `paid` and `later` in this query? Like this [example](http://joxi.ru/KAx7RabuloWn28)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `IN` if you want to find the sum of the two columns

```
sum(case when `order`.order_status in ('paid', 'later') then 1 end)
```

Comment: I mean to add new string in the end with total. Add example in question.

Comment: @stand - Why would you want to do that. Since 'total' is not a real delivery method, does it make any sense to have it in the column `order_customFields_delivery_method`? No. It doesn't.

Comment: I want to get total for all `order_customFields_delivery_method`

Answer (score 1):

you can just put `+` and you will have total

```
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then 1 else 0 end)+
    sum(case `order`.order_status when 'later' then 1 else 0 end) total
```

Comment: I mean to add new string in the end with total. Add example in question.

Comment: if you want like as example you need to use union by using different query sum of all

Answer (score 1):

You can just do an addition using addition operator - "+"

```
SELECT order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method,

    sum(sum(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then 1 else 0 end) +
    sum(case `order`.order_status when 'later' then 1 else 0 end)) total
FROM order_customFields 
  INNER JOIN `order` ON order_customFields.order_id = `order`.order_id

where `order`.order_createdAt >= date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day), interval 1 month) 
and `order`.order_createdAt < date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day)
AND order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method in('a','b','c','d','e')
GROUP BY    
   order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method
```

Please refer the MYSQL Documentation for more details - [Arithmetic Operations - MYSQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html)

Comment: I mean to add new string in the end with total. Add example in question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method,
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then 1 else 0 end)+
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'later' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM order_customFields 
INNER JOIN `order` ON order_customFields.order_id = `order`.order_id
where `order`.order_createdAt >= date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval 
day(curdate()) - 1 day), interval 1 month) 
and `order`.order_createdAt < date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day)
AND order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method in('a','b','c','d','e')
GROUP BY    
order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method`
```

Comment: I mean to add new string in the end with total. Add example in question.